# Isometric <=> Left Inverse Adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Is it true that:
$$T\text{ isometric}\iff T^*\text{ left inverse}$$
Obviously:
$$\text{"}\Rightarrow\text{": }\langle x,\tilde{x}\rangle=\langle Tx,T\tilde{x}\rangle=\langle x,T^*T\tilde{x}\rangle$$
$$\text{"}\Leftarrow\text{": }\langle Tx,T\tilde{x}\rangle=\langle x,T^*T\tilde{x}\rangle=\langle x,\tilde{x}\rangle$$
*My problem is that I'm not sure about if the adjoint is left inverse then the operator necessarily is bounded so that domain issues might come into play...*

Comment: No, there's a "$\rangle$" missing in the second inner product. Well, and you need to say _why_ that shows that $J^\ast J\tilde{x} = \tilde{x}$ for all $\tilde{x}$. If there doesn't appear a "for all" or two, it's not complete. But it's easily complete-able.

Comment: Well, thats obvious in my mind ;) i just wanted to give a sketch of the proof with its core statement. But apart from this there's nothing crucial missing, is it??

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you left out when stripping, so I make no guarantees. But apart from what you have, the other crucial ingredient is $H^\perp = \{0\}$, which I guess is obvious.

Comment: Yes this and that the adjoint is defined completely by this (??) in the bounded case...

Comment: I made a new thread on this slightly different...

Comment: @DanielFischer I posted an answer. I hope you don't mind. Otherwise let me know and I'll delete it.

Comment: I made a new thread on this and so will delete this one here by tomorrow since it's obsolete then - hope u don't mind. Here's the link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754979/isometry-adjoint-left-inverse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is an isometry then it has a left inverse that is:
$$\langle x,LRz\rangle=\langle x,z\rangle=\langle Rx,Rz\rangle$$
So the adjoint must act as a left inverse too.

On the other hand if the adjoint acts as a left inverse then:
$$\langle Rx,Ry\rangle=\langle x,R^*Ry\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$$
Thus it is an isometry.

*(Note, there's no need of completeness nor identification with dual space.)*

Answer (score 1):

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space and let $T \in B(H)$ be an isometry.  We claim that $T^\ast T = I$. To this end let $h \in H$ and note that by the Hilbert space Riesz representation theorem a linear functional in $H^\ast$ corresponds to an element $h \in H$ ($h \mapsto \langle  \cdot, h \rangle$).  Also note that if $\varphi (x) = 0$ for all $\varphi \in H^\ast$ then $x=0$.

Hence if for all $h, h' \in H$:

$$ \langle h, T^\ast T h' - h'\rangle = 0,$$

then $T^\ast T h' = h'$ for all $h' \in H$.

But since $T$ is an isometry

$$ \langle h, T^\ast T h' - h'\rangle = \langle h, T^\ast T h' \rangle-\langle h, h'\rangle = \langle Th,Th'\rangle - \langle h,h'\rangle = \langle h, h'\rangle -  \langle h, h'\rangle= 0,$$

hence $T^\ast T = I$ as desired.

Comment: It is perhaps worthwhile to insert the form $\langle Th,Th'\rangle - \langle h,h'\rangle$ before $\langle h,h'\rangle - \langle h,h'\rangle$ to make it clearer why $\langle h,T^\ast Th'\rangle$ is transformed into $\langle h,h'\rangle$. But it's fine.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for your comment! I agree but I will not edit it to avoid bumping this thread.