# Isometry <=> Adjoint left inverse

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Is it true that:
$$T\text{ isometric}\iff T^*\text{ left inverse}$$
Obviously:
$$\text{"}\Rightarrow\text{": }\langle x,\tilde{x}\rangle=\langle Tx,T\tilde{x}\rangle=\langle x,T^*T\tilde{x}\rangle$$
$$\text{"}\Leftarrow\text{": }\langle Tx,T\tilde{x}\rangle=\langle x,T^*T\tilde{x}\rangle=\langle x,\tilde{x}\rangle$$
*My problem is that I'm not sure about if the adjoint is left inverse then the operator necessarily is bounded so that domain issues might come into play...*

Comment: An intentional duplication by Freeze_S, according to the Comment left on the original Question.

Comment: An isometric operator is bounded. Then so is the adjoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is an isometry then it has a left inverse that is:
$$\langle x,LRz\rangle=\langle x,z\rangle=\langle Rx,Rz\rangle$$
So the adjoint must act as a left inverse too.

On the other hand if the adjoint acts as a left inverse then:
$$\langle Rx,Ry\rangle=\langle x,R^*Ry\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$$
Thus it is an isometry.

*(Note, there's no need of completeness nor identification with dual space.)*

Comment: To accept an answer you [posted elsewhere](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/761546/9003), to a duplicate question you posted above is abusing the system, and is inappropriate (not to mention accepting your duplicate answer to a duplicate question you yourself asked). Do not post a question that has already been answered by yourself, so you can answer and accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

$T$ must be densely defined for $T^\ast$ to be defined. That $T^\ast$ is a left inverse of $T$ implies that $\mathcal{R}(T) \subset \mathcal{D}(T^\ast)$. And hence for every $x \in \mathcal{D}(T)$ we have

$$\langle x,x\rangle = \langle x, T^\ast T x\rangle = \langle Tx,Tx\rangle,$$

or in other words $\lVert Tx\rVert = \lVert x\rVert$, i.e. $T$ is an isometry (and can hence be extended continuously to the entire space, still as an isometry, if it was not originally globally defined).

Comment: ...and then since it is an isometry the adjoint of the extension is its left inverse??

Comment: Yes. In particular (even before extending $T$ if necessary) it follows that $T^\ast$ is globally defined (and continuous).

Comment: How can you guarantee this?

Comment: How can I guarantee what? That $T^\ast$ is globally defined and continuous? That follows from the fact that $T$ is densely defined and continuous.

Comment: Ok thanks ;) ...